# What levels in LittleBigPlanet 2 have four-player/x4 challenges?

Tags: little-big-planet-2

I've got some friends coming over this weekend, and am thinking about asking them to help me complete the four-player/x4 challenges in [LittleBigPlanet 2](http://www.littlebigplanet.com/en/2/). I still have two worlds to complete to finish the game. The only one I've encountered so far is on *The Factory: Bang for Buck*. I'd like to know, before my friends arrive, how much further I have to get in the game to open all the 4x challenges.

**What levels have four-player challenges?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's [only two](http://www.littlebignetwork.com/showthread.php/9320-Co-Op-Multiplayer-Challenges-in-Story-Mode) in the story mode:

- Bung for Buck in The Factory of A Better Tomorrow
- Casa Del Higginbotham in Eve's Asylum

(Also listed [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/954843-/57998896) on GameFAQs)